# Reducing ZedGraph margin

Tags: c#, zedgraph

Can anyone please tell me how to reduce the margin between my graphPane to the border? I want to start at the bottom edge of the graph, have some clearance on top, left and right of the graph.  I tried this but it gives me some weird zoomed in figure.

```
graphPane.YAxis.Scale.Min = lowerPoint;
graphPane.YAxis.Scale.Max = higherPoint+offset;
graphPane.XAxis.Scale.Min = leftPoint + offset;
graphPane.XAxis.Scale.Max = rightPoint + offset;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can remove the 'margin' by manually setting the Rect property of the Chart

```
float leftMargin = 10;
float rightMargin = 10;
float topMargin = 10;
float bottomMargin = 5;
float width = 1920;
float height = 1080;
graphPane.Chart.Rect = new RectangleF(leftMargin, topMargin, width - leftMargin - rightMargin, height - topMargin - bottomMargin);
```